# How would I trigger a component function from a custom directive similar to (click)="handler()"?

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

I have a custom event directive called enterListener defined like so

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Output, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[enterListener]'
})

export class EnterKeyDirective {
    @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
    onEnter($event: any) {
        if ($event.key === 'Enter') {
            this.emitter.emit($event);
        }
    }
}
```

And its implemented in my html like so

```
<input (enterListener)="search()" id="searchBar" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" class="card-img" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is basically what the (click) event listener does, if a specific thing happens, a click, execute a specific function. For my directive, if the user presses enter then execute my method called, `search()`.

Right now on any key up I successfully break into my directive which exists in a file separate of my component file. And it successfully recognizes when the enter key is pressed.

But it won't trigger my `search()` function. What am I missing to make the directive recognize that an event handler is attached to it similar to how (click)="aMethod()" functions?

Comment: I don't understand.. why not just use `(keyup.enter)="search()"` ?

Comment: TIL that's a thing.. And I'm definitely embarrassed by how much I've been messing around with my own custom implementation for no good reason, haha.

Comment: I think that is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a directive, you need to bind with the name of the event emitter declared in the directive

```
<input [enterListener] (emitter)="search($event)" id="searchBar" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" class="card-img" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

Otherwise, as suggested, you can directly check for keyup in component's template, on input element

Comment: This answers my question, and I learned something new about the use of [ ] vs  ( ) because of it, thanks!. But I think the best approach is going to be (keyup.Enter). So I'll be scrapping the custom-directive.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `HTML` to something like this

```
<input (keyup)="search()" id="searchBar" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" class="card-img" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```